# install4j: Form with dynamic count of items/objects

Tags: forms, install4j

My installation involves 2 steps:

1. Enter count of entities (could be number between 1 and 100)
2. Enter some details for each entity (e.g. host, port, url, etc.)

I'm able to create form for the first entity with all the input fields including validations and store entered details in variables. But I don't know how to simply reuse existing form to collect details for the remaining entities. I don't want to copy+paste this form (and variables) hundred times and use some visibility script to show only first N forms.

**Is there some built-in component that could dynamically generate form/variables for each entity (based on the entered count)?** In ideal case with next/previous feature, and command line support. I cannot find any help/documentation related to this problem.

I'm using install4j 6.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a screen group do iterate. Right-click on the form screen and select "Create screen group from selection" from the context menu. In the configuration of the screen group, select the "Loop" property and configure its child property to set up looping. The installer variable configured in the "Loop index variable name" property can be used in the form screen.

Comment: Thank you. It seems fine, but what about dynamic variables? Is it possible to save values (String,Long,Boolean) from this looped forms easily into some lists or arrays? Or create some custom POJO and list of POJOs? Documentation with example would be very helpful.

Comment: Installer variables can have any type, so you can set up the installer variable `myList` with `context.setVariable("myList", new ArrayList())` before the loop. Then you can add elements to this list in the loop. You cannot do this directly with form components, they are always bound to the same installer variable, but in the validation script of the form you can transfer the bound values to an installer variable that holds a list or an array.

Comment: Thank you @Ingo! I appreciate your help.